# Why npm has newer version of packages than bower

Tags: npm, bower

I am using [ng-prettyjson](https://github.com/darul75/ng-prettyjson) in my project. For dependencies management I am using [bower](http://bower.io/).
After setting dependency to the ng-prettyjson to the next one `"ng-prettyjson": "~0.1.6"`, I am receiving information

```
> bower not-cached    git://github.com/darul75/ng-prettyjson.git#~0.1.6
> bower resolve       git://github.com/darul75/ng-prettyjson.git#~0.1.6
> bower ENORESTARGET  No tag found that was able to satisfy ~0.1.6
> 
> Additional error details: Available versions: 0.1.3, 0.1.1
```

If you check on [ng-prettyjson github page](https://github.com/darul75/ng-prettyjson/releases) it is true - only 2 releases, but if you take a look into  [ng-prettyjson npm repository](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-prettyjson) there is `0.1.6.` as the latest version. What is more if you try to install this component with npm you will install `0.1.6` version.

Is there any way to instruct bower to use as well npm repository for searching dependencies? Does it make sense to do such a thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot instruct bower to do this. This is because Bower will need additional information about the bower component (like dependencies, version, etc.). This information is needed to resolve the dependencies in your bower-components folder.

Most dependencies have build automation to update their bower and npm repositories, so I think you will not always get this problem. If you really need the most recent version of prettyjson, you could use npm for this specific dependency, or ask the developer to update it's bower repository.

Answer (score 1):

I have just released a new version, thank you for warning me about it, you can download version here or with bower.

[0.1.6 release](https://github.com/darul75/ng-prettyjson/releases/tag/0.1.6)